# Can WPA2 devices work with WPA2/WPA3?

Tags: wireless-networking

We have a Synology RT2600ac router. Upon seeing the WPA2/WPA3 setting, we had assumed that it would provide WPA3 to devices that support the newer standard, and WPA2 for devices that don't. However, when using this setting, my iPad 4th generation running iOS 10 was not able to connect at all. What exactly does the WPA2/WPA3 setting do if devices that only support WPA2 don’t work? Is it possible for such devices to work with WPA2/WPA3?

Comment: Certainly the intention of the mixed mode was exactly as you had assumed, but it sounds like your obsolete iPad's WPA2 implementation happened to choke on something new it saw.

Comment: There were many reports from users regarding this issues over the internet. Some users reported that they have upgraded iOS versions and it works, but I’m not sure about it.

Comment: @TimBerty The issue is, the iPad 4th generation doesn’t support any newer iOS version.

Comment: Then it won't work. If Apple won't provide an update that supports the newer features, then you cannot use them.

Comment: So what exactly is WPA2/WPA3 if the WPA2 part of it doesn’t support older devices?